# How to join variable with string in query?

Tags: php

I don't know why it did not work. i think it should work. if i change the $page in query with 0. it worked. instead use variable. it did not work.

PHP

```
$page = 0;

$query = $sql = "SELECT `Id`, `Title`, `Genre`, `Images`, `Url`, `Width`, `Height` FROM `contents` LIMIT 10 OFFSET '".$page."'";
```

Comment: It's a number, not a string, so no quotes around $page in your SQL query

Comment: @MarkBaker so it should be '.$page.' ?

Comment: No, the double quotes are you string encapsulation, single are for SQL encapsulation, get rid of single. You can just put the variable inside the double quotes. `LIMIT 10 OFFSET $page"`

Comment: Btw you can calculate the offset this way: `$offset = ($page - 1) * 10;`.

Comment: note that if that `$page` variable comes from the request in stead of being hard coded you should really be using prepared statements, or you'll be vulnerable to sql injection

Answer (score 1):

Your `$page` is a number, so you should do:

```
$sql = "SELECT `Id`, `Title`, `Genre`, `Images`, `Url`, `Width`, `Height` FROM `contents` LIMIT 10 OFFSET ". $page;
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are using page from an parameter, consider using prepared statements for security considerations.

[PHP Prepared Statements](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp)

```
$page = 0;
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// prepare and bind
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT `Id`, `Title`, `Genre`, `Images`, `Url`, `Width`, `Height` FROM `contents` LIMIT 10 OFFSET ?");
$stmt->bind_param("i", $page);
```

just write your sql statements in the prepared Statement and assign afterwards your params with $stmt->bind_param.

With this, php will automatically check if the variable holds the right datatype and will prevent your code from being vunerable by sql injection.

Answer (score 0):

As other mentioned, you're using your $page as a string. Most of the times PHP is forgiving, but youyr now making a query,m those are not so flexible.

Because of your quotes, your code results in this:

```
OFFSET '0' // See the quotes?
OFFSET 0 // no quotes is what you're looking for
```

VERY simply put, you now pass it as string. You as human see *number* 1, but the code sees *text* 1, which has about the same worth as `OFFSET 'a'`, it doesn't make sense for the interpreter.

---

Also, if you want the first results, you don't need the offset. Also, there is a shorthand version of waht you have:

```
LIMIT 10,25
```

This will give you 10 items, with an offset of 25.